# What does the word "Blob" mean, used in German anno 2016? And what's its etymology?

Tags: etymology, terminology, informal

Here's a sentence from a patient speaking to her youth psychiatrist:

> Weil Sie auf das, was ich sagte, keine Emotion zeigten, nur eine Antwort ausspuckten: Blob. *(Source: [DIE ZEIT ONLINE, 1 December 2016](http://www.zeit.de/2016/48/jugendpsychologie-suizid-therapie-beziehung))*

What is the meaning of the term "blob" here (and are there any other meanings), and what is its etymology please? Is it correct to assume that this is a rather informal term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seemingly nonsensical talk is sometimes called *Geblubber* in German. This most probably derives from the sound bubbles make when emerging from the water - it is a sound that is annoying enough to be heard but meaningless.

I'd guess that *Blob*, like *Plopp* oder *Blubb*, is used here to indicate that what the person said was just a waste of air.

The word itself - other than *Plopp* or *Blubb* - does not seem to be a German "word" at all.

Comment: The terms and explanation you gave here reminds me of the concept of "flatus vocis" in the nominalism of Roscellinus van Compiègne, who took his position in the debate over the problem of universals in Western medieval philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

*Blob* doesn't mean anything in German. Thus no other meanings, and no etymology.

With a lot of imagination, I could imagine it is a onomatopoeic expression featuring a goldfish in the glass, even if the text makes no further reference to it.

Answer (score -2):

Blob probably originated from [BLOB (Binary large object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object).

However, it is used whenever something withouth feelings or expression is described. Often people have an image of a green, slimish creature in mind ([example](https://pixabay.com/p-161097/?no_redirect)).

Thus, the term used by *ZEIT ONLINE* is rather coloquial

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but that is a weird etymology - the acronym looks modelled after the proper English term (*blob* meaning an indescript mass or drop), not the other way around. It doesn't help in the example of the OP either - a psychiatry patient answering in binary sure is insane, but that strikes me as an unlikely interpretation here.

Comment: I'm also not the downvoter. While it is true that BLOB is short for Binary Large Object in **Computer Science** terms, I doubt that any normal person would use that word (or the long form), especially in the given context.

Comment: @Iris, I downvoted for the reasons explained by others and ask: Why the upvotes?

Comment: Carsten S, although I disagree with the binary large object, the interpretation of a a blob as something without feeling or expression sound valid.

Comment: And here’s the second downvoter. I basically downvoted for the reason Thorsten gave. The key element of your post looks *extremely* wrong (I’m somewhat programming affine and yet never heard the term BLOB; the editors of the *ZEIT* most certainly won’t). I *never* encountered BLOB in that meaning colloquially. It doesn’t help you imho to draw the right conclusion from a wrong premise.

Comment: My point wasn't that the term *Blob* was inspired by the meaning of the Computer Science term. However, as it is rather a sound than a word, people might have found the term hilarious and thus started spreading it otherwise.

Comment: Don't think so - You'd need to be a database expert to know what a Blob is.

Comment: I am a hobby programmer and I perfectly know what BLOBs are. And I think everyone who seriously works with databases does, too.

Comment: If it helps, the "amorphus glob" meaning in english apparently goes back to middle english and wiktionary has cites back to 1869. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/blob … also, the post just like a wrong etymology, not a speculation of anything.